# My global flair suddenly includes meta.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, support, flair

I've had reputation above 200 here for quite some while now, but just now I noticed that my combined profile flair now *does* include this site. I'm pretty sure this wasn't so yesterday (or perhaps the day before). Any changes in policy there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your flair only includes up to seven sites where you have more than 200 reputation. Previously, Server Fault was your seventh top site as far as reputation ([see your accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/1914880/vonbrand?tab=accounts)), and you just passed that amount here on Meta which makes Meta.SO your seventh top site now:

[image: network graph showing MSO reputation surpassing Server Fault reputation]

There have been no changes in policy, only changes in your reputation. Flair images are heavily cached and do take a while to update.

Comment: You have Eagle eyes!